# How to switch styles in a vue vuetify app when changing the languge?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

so I am building a vueJs app using vuetify and vue-i18n for internationalization so i have this font-family that I want just to be applied on the Arabic language, so I will be switching styles when changing the language.
For now that's my function :

```
changeLanguage: function (lang) {
      this.$i18n.locale = lang
      localStorage.setItem('lang',lang);
    },
```

knowing that I can apply the rtl functionality that comes with vuetify but does it give me options to change the font-family (load a different style) ?
if not is there any solution for this problem ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which is very simple:
I created two files :

```
// ArabicFont.css
*{
   font-family: "my font for arabic lang" !important;
}
```

and

```
// MainFont.css
*{
  font-family: "my font for other cases" !important;
}
```

and when changing the language a page refresh should be applied to load the proper css file by adding this code to the main app component :

```
<template>
    <router-view />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted: function(){
        let lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')
        if(!lang) localStorage.setItem('lang',this.$i18n.locale)
//section added :
        if(lang){
            if(lang === 'ar'){
                import ("./assets/css/ArabicFont.css");
            }else{
                import("./assets/css/MainFont.css")

            }
            this.$i18n.locale = lang;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and the function `changeLanguage`  will become like this :

```
 changeLanguage: function (lang) {
      this.$i18n.locale = lang
      localStorage.setItem('lang',lang);
//added this line to refresh the page:
      this.$router.go()
    },
```

and that's it, it worked very well for me !

Comment: You can do it without page reload. Just toggle class to parent like `arab` instead of `this.$router.go()` and write css like this 
`.arab *{font-family: "my font for other cases" !important;}` in one css file